# How to fix NoSuchElementException (using XPath expressions with Selenium)

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, metamask

I am trying to have Selenium import metamask. However, when I use the XPath expression `/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button`, my console returns:

> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/)/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button"}
> (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)

Which is strange as when I use `$x("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button")` in [Chrome DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/devtools/), it is able to identify the <kbd>Get Started</kbd> button. How can I fix this error and why am I getting said error?

Full source code:

```python
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_extension('metamask-chrome-9.8.4.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options = options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

time.sleep(2)

get_started_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button")
get_started_button.click()

input('Press [ENTER] to close browsers...')

driver.quit()
```

Full Error Log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Rias\metamask selenium\script.py", line 13, in <module>
    get_started_button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button")
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 394, in find_element_by_xpath
    return self.find_element(by=By.XPATH, value=xpath)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 976, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/div/button"}
  (Session info: chrome=93.0.4577.82)
```

Comment: Please post html.

Comment: Check if the element is an `iframe` or `shadow-root`.

Comment: @normon99 : Is it possible to share page URL ?

Comment: I can but you need to install the metamask extension to get be able to access the URL. Would you link the link to the extension? I believe it redirects you to that url when its your first itme installing

Comment: https://pastebin.com/PnUJtAuY

The button // html I'm trying to click is ```</style></div><div class="main-container-wrapper"><div class="first-time-flow">```

Comment: @noromon99 :  See below and let me know if you run into any issue.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

There are four ways to click in Selenium.

I will use this XPath expression:

```
//button[text()='Get Started']
```

**Code trial 1:**

```python
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Get Started']").click()
```

**Code trial 2:**

```python
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[text()='Get Started']"))).click()
```

**Code trial 3:**

```python
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Get Started']")
driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", button)
```

**Code trial 4:**

```python
time.sleep(5)
button = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//button[text()='Get Started']")
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(button).click().perform()
```

**Imports:**

```python
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

**PS:** Please check in the dev tools if we have unique entry in HTML [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) or not.

**Steps to check:**

Press <kbd>F12</kbd> in Chrome → go to element section → do a <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd> → then paste the XPath expression and see, if your desired element is getting highlighted.

Comment: This seems to be a overgeneralised answer (posted to many questions?) that doesn't really answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

When you load the metamask extension to your Selenium driver (Chrome), there's a redirect that happens to the metamask page that you can see through the opened Chrome window.

But Selenium couldn't find the button, because it still sees the first tab as its active tab, so it looks for the button in the wrong place and the wrong tab.

You have to change the active tab in Selenium to be the metamask tab. See the below snippet:

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import time

options = Options()
options.add_extension('metamask-chrome-9.8.4.crx')

driver = webdriver.Chrome('./chromedriver', options = options)
driver.get('https://google.com')

time.sleep(2)

driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])

get_started_button = driver.find_element_by_class_name("first-time-flow__button")
get_started_button.click()

input('Press [ENTER] to close browsers...')

driver.quit()
```

I just added this line:

```
driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

to switch to the extension page and changed selecting the button by XPath to be by *class_name*.

It works fine with me.