# Selenium doesn't see password box of Metamask

Tags: python, selenium, metamask

```
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import time


opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile_path = r'C:\\Users\\*UserName*\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\UserData'
opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(profile_path)) # profile path
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format('DEFAULT')) #profile name
opt.add_argument('--log-level=3')
EXTENSION_PATH = 'MM/metamask.crx'
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('Driver/chromedriver.exe',  chrome_options=opt)
global_dynamicUrl = "https://pulsedao.finance/boardroom"
driver.get(global_dynamicUrl)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("MuiButton-label").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/nav/button[1]/span[1]").click()


password="**********"


driver.implicitly_wait(20)
driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//div[contains(@class, "metamask tw-flex tw-items-center tw-p-3")]')).click()
search_box=driver.find_element(By.XPATH,('//div[contains(@class, "metamask tw-flex tw-items-center tw-p-3")]'))
time.sleep(5)
search_box.send_keys(password)
time.sleep(2)
search_box.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
```

Gives the error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="password"]"}
```

I tried numerous other paths:

```
#Tried by xpath:
#//*[@id="password"]
#//*[@id="app-content"]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div
#('//input')
#'/*[@id="password"]' -> AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'send_keys'
#'/html/body/div[1]/div/div[3]/div/div/form/div/div/input'
#Tried by ID:
#
# Tried by selector
# #password
#'//div[contains(@class, "metamask tw-flex tw-items-center tw-p-3")]'
```

I followed this at the beginning:
https://dev.to/ltmenezes/automated-dapps-scrapping-with-selenium-and-metamask-2ae9
and didn't work either.
I tried checking similar questions here on stack, but with so success.

So after several hours of research I feel clueless. Maybe also because I come from Data Science and I attempt this for the first time, even if I have a basic understanding of python.

Comment: Please share ALL your code, not only locators you tried

Comment: done, even if I feel skeptical it will help you

Comment: I can't believe code you pasted works. It should throw `NoSuchElementException` even before completing the login

Comment: I had issues too before arriving to

driver.get(global_dynamicUrl)
driver.find_element_by_class_name("MuiButton-label").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div[3]/div[3]/nav/button[1]/span[1]").click()

if you refer to that

Comment: Yes, I mean that.

Comment: my suspect seems related to that:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69239129/how-to-fix-nosuchelementexception-using-xpaths-with-selenium/69669412#69669412
I didn't solve it anyway

Answer (score 0):

Find the password field using its class

`driver.find_elements_by_class_name('passwordClass').send_keys("password here")`

Comment: if I remove the s from elements:
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".passwordClass"}
if not: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'send_keys'

Comment: the class of password fild in MetaMask extension signup is `MuiInputBase-input` & `MuiInput-input` Test both

Comment: selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".MuiInputBase-input"}

and


selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".MuiInput-input"}
  (Session info: chrome=99.0.4844.51)

Answer (score 0):

You are missing waits here.
You should wait for elements to be loaded on the page before accessing them.
The preferred approach is to use Expected Conditions explicit waits.
This should work better:

```py
import re
from datetime import datetime as dt

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.select import Select
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import TimeoutException
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait

import time


opt = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
profile_path = r'C:\\Users\\*UserName*\\AppData\\Local\\Google\\Chrome\\UserData'
opt.add_argument('--user-data-dir={}'.format(profile_path)) # profile path
opt.add_argument('--profile-directory={}'.format('DEFAULT')) #profile name
opt.add_argument('--log-level=3')
EXTENSION_PATH = 'MM/metamask.crx'
opt.add_extension(EXTENSION_PATH)
driver = webdriver.Chrome('Driver/chromedriver.exe',  chrome_options=opt)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)

global_dynamicUrl = "https://pulsedao.finance/boardroom"
driver.get(global_dynamicUrl)
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.MuiButton-label"))).click()
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='Metamask']"))).click()
```

I can't continue from here since I didn't install the extension you are using here and I don't have your credentials but you can see from here how the thinngs working and continue in the similar way

Comment: but in this way the loaded elements appear in the extention icon? Basically what I don't want because I prefer a different tab.
It looks like my code doesn't work because it seems to locale 
element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id="password"]"} in a different tab I want it to wrk

Comment: What do you mean by "loaded elements appear in the extension icon"?

Comment: that metamask login appeasr as a popup in the extension icon.
Anyway I tried to switch tabs with driver.switch_to.window, and of course no difference.